# ASP.NET AJAX CollapsiblePanelExtender1 still active on next CollapsiblePanelextender2

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have 3 CollapsiblePanelExtender controls on one form that are collapsed by their individual button. I can collapse each unit but each time I click the next button to collapse the next, the previous CollapsiblePanelExtender takes one extra step first (either expand or collapse, while the clicked control remains unchanged) and the clicked unit collapses on a second click and so on. After the second click, it will expand/collapse until I go to the next one. Is there any known ways to stop this carry-over effect. Here's a bit of the code:
protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientState = "false";
            CollapsiblePanelExtender1.ClientState = "true";
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using panels instead and setting them to visible=true/false.